# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1), getting an unexpected 'Conversion failed' error.

Not quite sure how to describe this problem, so below is a simple example. The CTE extracts the numeric portion of certain IDs using a search condition to ensure a numeric portion actually exists. The CTE is then used to find the lowest unused sequence number (kind of):

```
CREATE TABLE IDs (ID CHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO IDs (ID) VALUES ('A01'), ('A02'), ('A04'), ('ERR');

WITH ValidIDs (ID, seq)
AS 
(
 SELECT ID, CAST(RIGHT(ID, 2) AS INTEGER)
   FROM IDs 
  WHERE ID LIKE 'A[0-9][0-9]'
)
SELECT MIN(V1.seq) + 1 AS next_seq
  FROM ValidIDs AS V1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM ValidIDs AS V2
                    WHERE V2.seq = V1.seq + 1
                  );
```

The error is, 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'RR' to data type int.'

I can't understand why the value `ID = 'ERR'` should be being considered for conversion because the predicate `ID LIKE 'A[0-9][0-9]'` should have removed the invalid row from the resultset.

When the base table is substituted with an equivalent CTE the problem goes away i.e.

```
WITH IDs (ID)
AS
(
 SELECT 'A01'
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A02'
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A04'
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'ERR' 
),
ValidIDs (ID, seq)
AS 
(
 SELECT ID, CAST(RIGHT(ID, 2) AS INTEGER)
   FROM IDs 
  WHERE ID LIKE 'A[0-9][0-9]'
)
SELECT MIN(V1.seq) + 1 AS next_seq
  FROM ValidIDs AS V1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM ValidIDs AS V2
                    WHERE V2.seq = V1.seq + 1
                  );
```

Why would a base table cause this error? Is this a known issue?

---

UPDATE @sgmoore: no, doing the filtering in one CTE and the casting in another CTE still results in the same error e.g.

```
WITH FilteredIDs (ID)
AS 
(
 SELECT ID
   FROM IDs 
  WHERE ID LIKE 'A[0-9][0-9]'

), 
ValidIDs (ID, seq)
AS 
(
 SELECT ID, CAST(RIGHT(ID, 2) AS INTEGER)
   FROM FilteredIDs 
)
SELECT MIN(V1.seq) + 1 AS next_seq
  FROM ValidIDs AS V1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM ValidIDs AS V2
                    WHERE V2.seq = V1.seq + 1
                  );
```

Comment: The core CTE works fine - try it by using `SELECT * FROM ValidIDs` instead of your query. The error must be somewhere else...

Comment: @marc_s: I agree the CTE is not the source of the problem. I'm not sure how CTEs work under the covers but I expect the CTE's query is merely expanded out into the query at parse time. Indeed, re-writing the query using two derived tables (each with the exact same syntax, of course) still exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug and has already been reported as [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) (as I said, it's hard to describe this one!) by Erland Sommarskog.

The response from the SQL Server Programmability Team is, "the issue is that SQL Server raises errors [too] eagerly due to pushing of prediates/expressions during query execution without considering the logical result of the query."

I've now voted for a fix, everyone do the same please :)

Comment: Also can occur in Oracle by the look of this Q. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46287236/73226

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace the section

```
SELECT ID, CAST(RIGHT(ID, 2) AS INTEGER)
FROM IDs 
WHERE ID LIKE 'A[0-9][0-9]'
```

With

```
SELECT ID, CAST(RIGHT(ID, 2) AS INTEGER)
FROM 
(
    select ID from IDs 
    WHERE ID LIKE 'A[0-9][0-9]'
)
```

Comment: Very strange and no I don't understand it. The error seems to be on the line WHERE V2.seq = V1.seq + 1 

changing it to

WHERE isnumeric(v2.seq) = 1 and isnumeric(v1.seq) =1 and V2.seq = V1.seq + 1

works (for me)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I did a Union and was not careful to make sure both queries had their fields in the same order. Once I fixed that, it was fine.