# Unexpected output when using "where" condition after an inner query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was trying out a query and it was returning an error which I cannot explain. (5 th query ).
Can someone help me understand what is causing the error.

```
DROP TABLE #temp  

SELECT * INTO #temp  
FROM  
(  
SELECT 'A_100' Col  
union all  
SELECT 'A_101'   
union all  
SELECT 'A_102'  
union all  
SELECT 'A_103'  
union all  
SELECT 'A_104'  
union all  
SELECT 'B_104'  
) a  

-- 1
SELECT * FROM #temp where col like 'A%'
     
-- 2
SELECT replace(col,'A_','')  FROM #temp where col like 'A%'
     
--3
SELECT cast(replace(col,'A_','') as INT) FROM #temp where col like 'A%'     

-- 4
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT cast(replace(col,'A_','') as INT) Num
 FROM #temp a where col like 'A%'
) A
     
-- 5
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT cast(replace(col,'A_','') as INT) Num
 FROM #temp a where col like 'A%'
) A
WHERE A.Num>102
```

Comment: Just two questions: what exactly is the error message you get? Have you tried doing:- SELECT * FROM ( SELECT cast(replace(col,'A_','') as INT) Num  FROM #temp a where col like 'A%' ) A  where A.Num > 201 ? ........... Probably it should be SELECT * FROM ( (SELECT cast(replace(col,'A_','') as INT) Num  FROM #temp a where col like 'A%' ) as A where A.num > 102)

Comment: @Sayuri the error messagw that I am getting is "convertion failed when coverting b_104 to datatype int"

Comment: Related [Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764424/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-to-int)

Comment: @ypercube Throwing me up against Gordon and Aaron huh :) that's low.

Comment: @DanielE. I think Aaron has an answer in another, newer question which is better but I can't find it.

Comment: And now it's there (the better answer)

Answer (score 1):

@Sayuri That does not solve the error, and OP does do that check, the error should not be happening.

It also is not what is causing the error, as `SELECT replace(col,'A_','') from #temp where col like 'A%'` correctly outputs `100,101,102,103,104` there is something getting cached that shouldn't be. If it splits into a new #tmp table first instead of a nested `select` it then works correctly.

```
SELECT replace(col,'A_','') [Num]
INTO #tmp 
FROM #temp b 
WHERE col LIKE 'A%'

SELECT [Num]
FROM #tmp 
WHERE [Num] > 101
```

Complete Runnable Code

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM (
    SELECT 'A_100' Col
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A_101'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A_102'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A_103'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A_104'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B_104'
    ) a


SELECT cast(replace(col, 'A_', '') as int) Num
INTO #tmp
FROM #temp b
WHERE col LIKE 'A%'

SELECT *
FROM #tmp
WHERE Num > 101

DROP TABLE #tmp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: You'll still get the same error with the first statement of yours. If you only `SELECT Num ... WHERE ...` into the temp table and then do `SELECT REPLACE...` from it, it will work.

Comment: This runs just fine with OP's input data, the conversion is implicit in the second where clause.

Comment: @Daniel E. Are you sure the '104' you see is the casting from 'B_104' and not 'A_104'? I haven't executed the query but it clearly looks like the "replace" should fail for 'B_104'

Comment: I changed B_104 to B_105 just to check, it works both ways.

Comment: Why would the replace fail? there is a `where` filter...

Comment: For the same reason that it fails in the OP's code. See the link in @bummi's comment.

Comment: OPs code threw the error and mine does not, I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: OK, read the link, probably the same error, I suppose this is a working work around then.

Comment: Yes, I tested your code and seems to work. Not sure if it is a reliable workaround though.

Comment: @Sayuri the OP is trying to filter out the `B_104`, explicitly.  We don't want the 104 from that line.

Comment: if the order of operations is what is causing the bug this forces SQL server to do it in a more linear fashion.You will have the overhead of writing the records to the new `#tmp` table. 60% of the query cost here was writing those records to the new `#tmp` table...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue lies in this.

Your query is as follows:
SELECT cast(replace(col,'A_','') as INT) Num  FROM #temp a where col like 'A%'

It first tries to replace a col "A_" that matches 'A%' and casts it into an INT. Now, since 'b_104' does not meet the first criterion of being like 'A%'; replacement does not happen; hence casting to INT fails. You can try doing the following and see the output for yourself:

```
                      SELECT replace(col,'A_','') from #temp where col like 'A%'
```

And then try a select * on #temp

Comment: So, what solution do you suggest?

Comment: Well, your question was to help you get the error :) On second thoughts, try removing the criterion 'like "A%"'

Comment: It wasn't my question ;) Removing the WHERE will not help because the string with `'b_104'` will not be replaced.

Comment: @ypercube Aah, sorry mistook you as the one posting the question. Yeah, got it, he needs to replace both 'A_' and 'B_'. Thanks for pointing it out ;)   Ahem, now you could act generous and upvote my response :D

Comment: that is a red herring, and OP doesn't want to replace A_ and B_